# Selenium WebDriverError: unknown error: unknown sessionId

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

**I have:** Jenkins, Selenium Server Standalone 3.11.0, Chrome 65.0.3325.146 and Chromedriver 2.36.540471.

**Problem:** Since couple of days one of my tests started to failing on Jenkins with following error: "WebDriverError: unknown error: unknown session" - locally it's working without any problem.

**Here is the console output from Jenkins:**

```
[11:15:41] I/start - java -Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/./urandom -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.36 -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/geckodriver-v0.20.0 -jar /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.11.0.jar -port 4474
[11:15:41] I/start - seleniumProcess.pid: 9625
11:15:41.964 INFO [GridLauncherV3.launch] - Selenium build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3'
11:15:41.966 INFO [GridLauncherV3$1.launch] - Launching a standalone Selenium Server on port 4474
2018-03-13 11:15:42.112:INFO::main: Logging initialized @571ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
11:15:42.411 INFO [SeleniumServer.boot] - Welcome to Selenium for Workgroups....
11:15:42.411 INFO [SeleniumServer.boot] - Selenium Server is up and running on port 4474
...
[11:15:46] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[11:15:46] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4474/wd/hub
11:15:46.712 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.apply] - Capabilities are: Capabilities {browserName: chrome, chromeOptions: {args: [--headless, --disable-extensions, --disable-gpu, --no-sandbox, --disable-default-apps, --window-size=1600,1000]}, count: 1, version: ANY}
11:15:46.714 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.lambda$apply$11] - Matched factory org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSession$Factory (provider: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
Starting ChromeDriver 2.36.540471 (9c759b81a907e70363c6312294d30b6ccccc2752) on port 5633
Only local connections are allowed.
11:15:47.492 INFO [ProtocolHandshake.createSession] - Detected dialect: OSS
11:15:47.976 INFO [RemoteSession$Factory.lambda$performHandshake$0] - Started new session c69cbc9da3e084a1e6f43d74b8532431 (org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
Started
[1520936158.443][SEVERE]: Unable to retrieve document state unknown error: unknown sessionId
 [31mF [0m

Failures:
1) test for timeline should add new profile
  Message:
 [31m    Failed: unknown error: unknown sessionId
      (Session info: headless chrome=65.0.3325.146)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540471 (9c759b81a907e70363c6312294d30b6ccccc2752),platform=Linux 3.19.0-64-generic x86_64) [0m
  Stack:
    WebDriverError: unknown error: unknown sessionId
      (Session info: headless chrome=65.0.3325.146)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540471 (9c759b81a907e70363c6312294d30b6ccccc2752),platform=Linux 3.19.0-64-generic x86_64)
        at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/run all/workspace/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:505:15)
        at parseHttpResponse (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/run all/workspace/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
        at doSend.then.response (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/run all/workspace/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:440:13)
        at <anonymous>
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
    From: Task: WebDriver.findElements(By(css selector, input.text-input.text-input-md))
        at thenableWebDriverProxy.schedule (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/run all/workspace/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:816:17)
        at thenableWebDriverProxy.findElements (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/run all/workspace/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:1057:22)
        at ptor.waitForAngular.then (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/run all/workspace/node_modules/protractor/lib/element.ts:166:36)
        at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/run all/workspace/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1366:14)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/run all/workspace/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2970:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/run all/workspace/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2953:27)
        at asyncRun (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/run all/workspace/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2813:27)
        at /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/run all/workspace/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:676:7
        at <anonymous>Error
        at ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_ (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/run all/workspace/node_modules/protractor/lib/element.ts:482:23)
        at ElementArrayFinder.(anonymous function).args [as sendKeys] (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/run all/workspace/node_modules/protractor/lib/element.ts:96:21)
        at ElementFinder.(anonymous function).args [as sendKeys] (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/run all/workspace/node_modules/protractor/lib/element.ts:873:14)
        at WebAppProfile.setProfile (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/run all/workspace/tmp/page/web-app/profile-web-app.js:51:23)
        at /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/run all/workspace/tmp/test/profile/user-activity.js:26:43
        at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/run all/workspace/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1366:14)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/run all/workspace/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2970:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/run all/workspace/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2953:27)
        at asyncRun (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/run all/workspace/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2813:27)
        at /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/run all/workspace/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:676:7
    From: Task: Run it("should add new profile") in control flow
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/run all/workspace/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:94:19)
    From asynchronous test: 
    Error
        at Suite.<anonymous> (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/run all/workspace/tmp/test/profile/user-activity.js:16:5)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/run all/workspace/tmp/test/profile/user-activity.js:15:1)
        at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)

1 spec, 1 failure
Finished in 10.703 seconds

11:15:58.841 INFO [ActiveSessions$1.onStop] - Removing session c69cbc9da3e084a1e6f43d74b8532431 (org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
[11:15:58] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[11:15:58] I/launcher - chromeANY #01 failed 1 test(s)
[11:15:58] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)
Closing report
[11:15:58] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! app-e2e-tests@1.0.0 user-activity: `protractor tmp/specs/profile/user-activity-spec.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the app-e2e-tests@1.0.0 user-activity script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /var/lib/jenkins/.npm/_logs/2018-03-13T10_15_58_855Z-debug.log
Process leaked file descriptors. See https://jenkins.io/redirect/troubleshooting/process-leaked-file-descriptors for more information
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Recording test results
Finished: FAILURE
```

In this test I'm trying to visit website (it's a PWA) and send some data through form - according to screenshots test hangs when form modal is open. What's very confusing I'm using the same method for data sending in other tests and these tests are passing...

**Solution:** Local Chrome update (to v. 65) allowed me to look what's happening during problematic test - push notification pop up was interrupting form filling. I turned it down in my config and test works again.

Comment: Have you noticed that this is happening only in Chrome 65 and ChromeDriver 2.36? Are there other combinations that are currently working or have worked on Jenkins previously?

Comment: @cnishina locally I'm using Chrome 64 and ChromeDriver 2.36. Before I have Chrome 64 on Jenkins and test was working... Are you sugessting me to downgrade Chrome version?

Comment: If the test was originally working then it could be something with the chromedriver compatibility with the browser for your OS running linux. Just a quick search on the bug list, maybe you are not the only one with this problem? https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2054

Comment: Looks like it is a bigger problem with ChromeDriver: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5576

Comment: Problem solved - I've updated my post.

Comment: Please add an actual answer to your question and not update your question. It will help other people know this issue might be resolved and not just an open ended question. I'm glad you figured it out. Thanks!